# How to know if two commits conflict

Tags: svn

I have two local copies of a same repository. How I can check that if I do 'svn commit' from each copy then there will not be conflicts without explicit commit?

Comment: Just a guess, a couple of svn commands allow --dry-run i'm not sure though that it works with commit.

Comment: Does this [link](http://www.linxit.de/svnbook/en/1.1/ch03s05.html#svn-ch-3-sect-5.3) can be helpful for you?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I write delayed commit system. In simple words it takes your sources, test them and if it is ok then commit to svn. Problem is that submits are processed in parallel and I want to be sure that new submits don't conflict with in-flight submits

Comment: @krvladislav: As I wrote in my answer, commits never conflict, only updates do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to know that before checking in. Is it because you are afraid you mess up something by checking in? If so, then rest assured that this won't easily happen by accident.

Once you have committed from one project, you cannot commit (the same files of) the other project unless you update first, in which case you will have to resolve conflicts, should there be any.

If, however, you simply want to know whether changes to two working copies of the same repository will conflict, you can use any diff tool you want, including whatever `svn diff` invokes. (Note that the latter will work with two local paths, too.)

Comment: Can you describe scenarion with `svn diff` please?

Comment: @krvladislav: I rarely ever use the svn command line, but have you tried `svn diff wc1 wc2`?

Comment: This command works but there is no information about conflicts. Presence of changes between wc1 and wc2 is not same as conflict

Answer (score 0):

In this [link](http://www.linxit.de/svnbook/en/1.1/ch03s05.html#svn-ch-3-sect-5.3) there are explanation how to use the command `svn status` that can show the conflicted files.

Comment: However, that just shows conflicts with changes that are in the repository, not with changes in another working copy.

Comment: I don't sure if svn can compare working copies each other. I think always compare a working copy with the repository.